# getting a html element in a empty div via Jquery or knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have 3 buttons which on click should add a different container into the empty div which is outside

```
<button id="a" data-bind="clickme" value="1">a</button>
<div id="empty1"> 
<button id="b" data-bind="clickme" value="2">b</button>
<div id="empty2">  
<button id="c" data-bind="clickme" value="3">c</button>
<div id="empty3"> 

<!-- the container below should replace the empty div -->
<div class="container" id="big_container" data-bind="visible : openContainer">
<p> Hello world !</p> 
</div>
```

All the buttons are can connected via one knockout js data bind click me and has value and id.

What I would like to do is lets say that the button a is clicked, it should display the container on empty1 and if button 2 is clicked it should display big container  on the empty2. The container is hidden by a databind so it only will show when the button is clicked.

Here is the knockout js function i am using

```
self.openContainer = ko.observable(false);
self.clickme= function(value){
   if(value == 1){
   // make the observable visible so the container should display
      self.openContainer(true);
   $("#empty1").load("big_container");
   }
}
```

I am trying jquery which doesnt work, and also I tried knockout js component register but I am not sure how that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with jQuery. Please note that this moves the container to your empty div, it don't just copy the html content.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click','button[data-bind]',function(){
  jQuery('div#empty'+jQuery(this).val()).html(jQuery('div.container')) ;
  jQuery('div.container').show() ;
}) ;
```

```css
div#empty1, div#empty2, div#empty3 {
  border:1px solid red ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a" data-bind="clickme" value="1">a</button>
<div id="empty1"> </div>
<button id="b" data-bind="clickme" value="2">b</button>
<div id="empty2"> </div>
<button id="c" data-bind="clickme" value="3">c</button>
<div id="empty3"> </div>

<!-- the container below should replace the empty div -->
<div class="container" id="big_container" style="display:none;">
<p> Hello world !</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use knockout `templates` and use `ifs` to add them into the correct empty divs. With this the openContainer is actually redundant

JS:

```
self.openContainer = ko.observable(false);
self.btnClicked = ko.observable();
self.clickme= function(value){
   self.btnClicked(value)
   if(value == 1){
       self.openContainer(true);
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="a" data-bind="clickme" value="1">a</button>
<!-- ko if: btnClicked() == 1 -->
<div id="empty1" data-bind="template: { name: 'big-container-template' }"></div> 
<!-- /ko -->
<button id="b" data-bind="clickme" value="2">b</button>
<!-- ko if: btnClicked() == 2 -->
<div id="empty2" data-bind="template: { name: 'big-container-template' }"></div>  
<!-- /ko -->
<button id="c" data-bind="clickme" value="3">c</button>
<!-- ko if: btnClicked() == 3 -->
<div id="empty3" data-bind="template: { name: 'big-container-template' }"> </div> 
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/html" id="big-container-template">
  <!-- the container below should replace the empty div -->
  <div class="container" id="big_container" data-bind="visible : openContainer">
  <p> Hello world !</p> 
  </div>
</script>
```

**The clean version of this would then be:**

```
self.container = ko.observable();
self.clickme= function(value){
   self.container(value)
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ko if: container() == 1 -->
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'big-container-template' }"></div> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

or

```
<div data-bind="visible: container() == 1, template: { name: 'big-container-template' }"></div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/html" id="big-container-template">
  <div class="container">
      <p> Hello world !</p> 
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: for some reason my knockout js cannot find the closing tag of ko

Comment: No havent created a fiddle for it, but I am thinking it might be something with my knockout version

Comment: if the error is `cannot find the closing tag of ko`. This means you are missing `<!-- /ko -->`

Comment: I thought at first too but atleast triple checked it that it was there, I am trying with a different version hope it works

Comment: Just noticed in my example i was missing closing `</div>` tags, if you have the same this will result in same error. This was on #empty divs

Comment: ahhh, could be! since I followed your example and thought without </div> is the right way haha